# What does this code do? (final exam)

Tags: loops, for-loop

int[][] x = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 
int i, j;

```
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i=i+1) 
     { for (j = 0; j < 3; j=j+1) 
     System.out.print(x[i][j] + " "); 
     System.out.println();
```

Can you tell me the steps its doing..... im confused :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's probably not even going to compile because you're missing a closing bracket.

```
[some code...]
{
for (i = 0; i < 3; i=i+1) 
 { 
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j=j+1) 
     System.out.print(x[i][j] + " "); 
 }
     System.out.println();  
}
```

Here's **what this does**:

For each of the three (`i`) groups (for example {1, 2 ,3}), the three (`j`) members of the group (1, 2 and 3) and a new line will be printed.

**How it works**:

*First iteration* (i): i = 0;

----First iteration (j): j = 0; print x[0][0];

[...]

----Third iteration (j): j = 2; print x[0][2];

print new line;

*Second iteration* (i): i = 1;

----First iteration (j): j = 0; print x[1][0];

[...]

So, the output is going to look like a matrix:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9.